# Magento 1.7. Modify QuoteItem Name and Sku

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to modify a product's name and sku in a current quote (basket/checkout/sales order) only, but I can't get it to work.

I can get the quote item and change its price, but not the name or sku.  If I get the product from the observer I can set the name and sku but it changes it globally.

My observer watches this event;

```
<checkout_cart_product_add_after>
<observers>
    <Meltingpotdesign_Frs_Model_Observer>
        <type>model</type>
        <class>Meltingpotdesign_Frs_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>addNewPrice</method>
    </Meltingpotdesign_Frs_Model_Observer>
</observers>
</checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

And then the function;

```
public function addNewPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{

$quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();

// This doesnt do anything
$quoteItem->setSku('test1')->setName('newname')->save();

// This works, changing the price on the quote to the value $newprice
$quoteItem->setCustomPrice($newprice);
$quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($newprice);
$quoteItem->setIsSuperMode(true);

// This gets the actual product
$item = $observer->getProduct();
// This sets the name and sku of product globally (not what I'm after!)
// $item->setSku('test1')->setName('newname')->save()
}
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: "I can set the name and sku but it changes it globally." can you elaborate bit more? What you mean by globally here?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Yes sure - what I mean is it changes the product record in the catalogue, rather than just on this users order.

I would like to change the name and sku of the product on the customers session/basket/order only.